# Microsoft Visual C++ connection to a Unix environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to connect to a Solaris machine and read log files from the Unix environment so that I can parse data from the log and create reports. For parsing I thought of using VC++.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, because the user don't have knowledge to work in a Unix environment (console) and a GUI is not available.

How do I connect to a Unix environment using a VC++ program?

Comment: Map you Unix directory on to Windows using samba and read it .

Answer (score 2):

Surely you'd be better off getting, say, a Perl script running on the Solaris machine to parse the log and dump a file locally to the Solaris machine. IMHO, it's much easier to write these kind of 'log scrappers' in Perl or Python.

Then you could arrange for the directory on the Solaris machine to be shared out read-only via Samba, say, so that all your Windows C++ program would have to do would be to check for the existance of a file on the share and open it. Nothing more than local file opening capability needed here.

If sharing is not a possibility, then you'll be restricted by whatever the network team will allow you to use.